# How to set anti aliasing for a custom view from another library?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view, antialiasing

I'm using `BarChartView` from [Williamchart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart) library. As you can see in the image, the bars are not smooth and are pixelated:

[image]

Can I somehow set anti aliasing on this view?

```xml
<com.db.chart.view.BarChartView
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    app:chart_cornerRadius="3dp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

First check the library whether the paint object which draws the bar is not private. Then check whether the paint object is initialized in the constructor of the view or in any method can be overridden (`onDraw() is an exception`). Then if two of the cases is true, extend the BarChartView, override the appropriate method, call the super of the method, set the antiAliasFlag of the paint object to true. onDraw() is exception because when you call the super the view is already drawn so setting anti alias flag the paint doesn't make any change.